# Elasticsearch stops after import data from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

1. I deployed my app to vps.
2. Started Elasticsearch, and checked it with `ps aux | grep elasticsearch`
3. `cd app/currect` && `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails c`
4. `User.import`

   Output:

   ```
   Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size  
     User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 10
   Faraday::ConnectionFailed: connection refused: localhost:9200
   ```
5. Elasticsearch stopped and import doesn't work, why ?

I am using Ubuntu 14, Puma server, SQLite database. Does it matter?

**Additional notes:**

`https://github.com/rusikf/pmi_parser/blob/master/Gemfile.lock` - gemfile.lock from project

`http://pastebin.com/J6Wi8qBF` - elasticsearch config

`http://pastebin.com/3BKmZG4G` - elasticsearch log

Before User.import

`ps aux | grep elasticsearch`

shows elasticsearch process

After User.import
`ps aux | grep elasticsearch`
doesn't show process

How to check if elasticsearch uses 9200 port ?

Comment: Are you using the `elasticsearch-model` gem? Please add to the question: the relevant sections of your gemfile, with versions (rails, sqlite, elasticsearch-*), your ruby version, how you defined your elasticsearch index and mappings.

Comment: Also it might be a simple connection issue. On which port is elasticsearch running?

Comment: It looks like you can't connect to elastic search - make sure it's running, make sure it's bound to localhost, make sure it's bound to port 9200, and make sure that there's no networking thing that's preventing you from connecting.

Comment: What does your ES log say?

Comment: Hello all hackers, thanks for responses, I added additional notes for question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by changing ip to vps ip address:9200 + running `Model_name.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true` in rails console